# Download and save any web page as Unicode, using Delphi 2009?

Tags: html, delphi, http, winapi, internationalization

I wish to download a web page, which may be in any possible text encoding, and save it as UTF16LE.  Assuming I can determine the text's encoding (by examining the HTTP header, HTML header, and/or BOM), how do I convert the text?

I am using Delphi 2009.  Unfortunately, the help files do not explain how to get from *any* encoding to a Unicode (UTF16LE) string.  Specific questions:

- Can I complete the conversion, simply by setting the correct encoding on an AnsiString and assigning that to a UnicodeString?
- If so, how do I translate the various "charset" descriptions that may label the web page (Big5, Shift-JIS, UTF-32, etc) into the right format to initialize the AnsiString?

Thanks for your suggestions.

I have a preference for straight Win32 and VCL, but answers involving ActiveX controls may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how are you going to access the page? Embedded Internet Explorer, INDY, third party tool, ...? That might influence the answer because it determines the format of the input string.

**Part 1: Getting the page**

If you use the Embedded Internet Explorer (`TWebBrowser`) to access the page things are pretty straightforward:

```
var htmlElement:IHTMLElement;
    myText:String;
begin
  // Get access to the HTML element of the document:
  htmlElement:=(WebBrowserControl.DefaultInterface.Document as IHTMLDocument3).documentElement;
  // Receive the full HTML of the web page:
  myText:=htmlElement.OuterHTML;
```

The encoding of the web page should be handled properly by the IE and by Delphi and you end up with a `UnicodeString` containing the result (`myText` in the examples).

**Part 2: Saving in UTF-16LE**

Regardless where your string came from - you can save it like this in the desired encoding:

```
var s:TStringStream;
begin
  s:=TStringStream.Create(myText, TEncoding.Unicode, false);
  s.SaveToFile('yourFileToSaveTo.txt');
  FreeAndNil(s);
end;
```

`TEncoding.Unicode` is UTF-16LE, but you could also use any other encoding.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd like to warn about using TWebBrowser, since it brings with it IE's behavior. Things that can stop you from getting the page source using TWebBrowser include: multiple IE security settings pop up a manual confirmation box, Javascript errors, ActiveX controls, other incompatibility issues or any external link such as ads on the page cause a popup, Windows and possibly firewall/virus software may cause a popup, if the requested source is not of mime-type HTML you will get a Save As popup. Don't use it, that's my advice. There are plenty of alternatives such as Synapse.

Answer (score 2):

In D2009 and later, Indy 10's TIdHTTP component automatically decodes a received webpage to UTF-16 for you.

Doing a charset-to-Unicode conversion on Windows requires the use of codepages (unless you use the ICONV library), so you have to first convert a charset name to a suitable codepage, and then you can use TEncoding.GetEncoding() and TEncoding.GetString(), or call SetCodePage() on a RawByteString (not an AnsiString) that you then assign to a UnicodeString, to do the conversion (internally, Indy uses TEncoding and has its own charset-to-codepage lookup tables).